# PHP CLI won't log errors

Tags: php, command-line-interface, error-logging

PHP currently will not log errors produced from the command line.

I have:

```
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
```

in file */etc/php5/cli/php.ini*.

Am I missing a further setting to get this working?

Comment: for me, on centos, using php7.0 from remi repo, the issue was with `error_log = php_errors.log` in config. `error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log` was the solution.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Please check that the user account running PHP CLI has write access to `/var/log/php_errors.log`.

Additionally, you can verify that you are using the correct php.ini file like this:

```
php -a -c /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Comment: if nothing happens when I run that command does it mean CLI isn't using that php.ini file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "nothing happens," but you can determine what config file you are using by using phpinfo() and searching for "Loaded Configuration File"

Comment: Additionally, remember to use `-a`, which I left out of the original post (now fixed).

Comment: I meant it literally; it must have been due to the missing `-a`. So if it's using the right config file, which it is, and still nothing is being written to the log, then what?

Comment: Back to the first suggestion: Does your user account have write access to /var/log/php_errors.log?

Comment: Yes, and I alternate the testing between that location and /tmp to make sure as it ought to be able to write to /tmp at the very least!

Comment: What is the value of error_reporting? Default is "E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE".

Comment: After reading from a few different sources and testing locally, I am starting to get the sneaky suspicion that PHP CLI doesn't use the log file, regardless of the directives. Instead, it sends output only to stderr. You can force the issue like this: $`php -a >> /var/log/php_errors.log 2>&1`. Will that accomplish what you need?

Answer (score 48):

This question and answer thread was very helpful to me while setting up PHP CLI logging on an [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) environment, so I wanted to post an answer that distills  what I learned. In addition to the great information [provided by David Chan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19867274/117259) as well [as George Cummins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6387561/117259), I have created a `logrotate.d` script to ensure the PHP CLI error log doesn’t grow out of control as well as set this up so multiple users will be able to log errors to the common PHP CLI error log.

First, the default behavior of the PHP CLI is to log error messages to standard output; logging to a file is not default behavior. Which usually means logging to the same command line terminal session that is running the PHP CLI command. While the PHP ini file does have accommodations for a specified `error_log` additional accommodations need to be made to truly make it work.

First, I had to create an initial `php_errors.log` file:

```
sudo touch /var/log/php_errors.log
```

Since the server in question is used by web developers working on various projects, I have set up a common group for them called `www-users`. And in this case, I want the `php_errors.log` to be readable and writable by `www-users` I change the ownership of the file like this:

```
sudo chown root:www-users /var/log/php_errors.log
```

And then change the permissions of the file to this:

```
sudo chmod 664 /var/log/php_errors.log
```

Yes, from a security standpoint having a log file readable and writable by anyone in `www-users` is not so great. But this is a controlled shared work environment. So I trust the users to respect things like this. And besides, when PHP is run from the CLI, any user who can do that will need write access to the logs anyway to even get a log written.

Next, go into `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` to adjust the default Ubuntu 12.04 settings to match this new log file:

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Happily `log_errors` is enabled by default in Ubuntu 12.04:

```
log_errors = On
```

But to allow logging to a file we need to change the `error_log` to match the new file like this:

```
error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
```

#### Setup a `logrotate.d` script.

Now that should be it, but since I don’t want logs to run out of control I set a `logrotate.d` for the `php_errors.log`. Create a file called `php-cli` in `/etc/logrotate.d/` like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/logrotate.d/php-cli
```

And place the contents of this log rotate daemon script in there:

```
/var/log/php_errors.log {
        weekly
        missingok
        rotate 13
        compress
        delaycompress
        copytruncate
        notifempty
        create 664 root www-users
        sharedscripts
}
```

#### Testing the setup.

With that done, let’s test the setup using [David Chan’s tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19867274/117259):

```
php -r "error_log('This is an error test that we hope works.');"
```

If that ran correctly, you should just be bounced back to an empty command prompt since PHP CLI errors are no longer being sent to standard output. So check the actual `php_errors.log` for the test error message like this:

```
tail -n 10 /var/log/php_errors.log
```

And there should be a timestamped error line in there that looks something like this:

```
[23-Jul-2014 16:04:56 UTC] This is an error test that we hope works.
```

Comment: This answer combines the context of what is happening, suggest specific configuration changes and how to make them, solidifies the logging w/ a log rotation and tests the configuration. Some of it was inspired by other comments, but this is wrapped up perfectly in one place. Thanks @JakeGould.

Answer (score 17):

As a diagnostic, you can attempt to force a write to the error log this way:

```
php -c /etc/php5/cli/php.ini -r " error_log('test 123'); "
```

You should now see test 123 in your log:

```
tail /var/log/php_errors.log
```

Answer (score 5):

The logging/reporting behaviour of PHP is dependent on error_reporting too.

Some PHP frameworks (for example, [CodeIgniter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter)) execute an `error_reporting(E_STRICT)` statement or equivalent, when in production mode, which will severely reduce the number/kind of logged errors.

If you want to debug something, then you can just put the following statement right before your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't figure out what why or perhaps don't have user permissions on file *php.ini*, another way to debug a no-information parse error is to wrap your PHP source in another PHP source file with a body something like:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include "mybustedfile.php";
```

Answer (score 2):

**In the PHP file**

```
error_log("You messed up!", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
```

**In the terminal**

```
tail -f /var/tmp/my-errors.log
```

**Output**

*You messed up!*

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: `/var/tmp` belongs to user `root` on the system I am on ([Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa)).