# How to interact with PHP CLI through Java

Tags: java, php, command-line-interface

I'm planning to use a PHP library in my Java program by making a PHP CLI interactive shell with commands for all the functions I need, and then calling those from Java. Most of the commands will print a String to the console which I'll then parse in Java to the data I need.

Currently my Java code looks like this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "Q:\\Instagram\\new\\php.bat", "main.php");
        builder.directory(new File("Q:\\Instagram\\new"));
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        p.waitFor();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

        System.out.println("The first output is: ");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println("Output: " + scanner.nextLine());
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.write("Test two");
        writer.newLine();

        System.out.println("The second output is: ");

        scanner = new Scanner(reader);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println("Output: " + scanner.nextLine());
        }
```

And my PHP script, main.php, is:

```
<?php
print_r("Test One\n");
print_r(fgets(STDIN));
?>
```

With this code the output is empty, and the program keeps running.
When I remove `print_r(fgets(STDIN));` from the PHP file it outputs:

```
The first output is: 
Output: 
Output: Q:\Instagram\new>Q:\Robobot\PHP\php.exe main.php         main.php0 
Output: Test one
The second output is: 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now call me stupid, but should it output this if I didn't remove that line?

```
The first output is: 
Output: 
Output: Q:\Instagram\new>Q:\Robobot\PHP\php.exe main.php         main.php0 
Output: Test one
The second output is:
```

Then wait for the Java code to do:

```
writer.flush();
writer.write("Test two");
writer.newLine();
```

And then finally output:

```
Test two
Test two

Process finished with exit code 0
```

(Test two is show twice since the first time is the input into the console, and the second time the PHP script repeating it)

Some side info, I'm making this on Windows in IntelliJ but I plan on running it on Ubuntu eventually. The examples above are from me running it from inside IntelliJ, but I got the same result when I ran it from the command line.

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to run the PHP shell from Java. Input my command with the OutputStream, handle the command in PHP, print the result as a String and parse it in Java with the InputStream.

Comment: 1) That's hideous. 2) [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/).

Comment: Are you logging php errors? If so, are there any errors caused by the script? If you're not, please turn that on and try again. [This may help with setting up logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387542/php-cli-wont-log-errors)

Comment: @Terminus no errors.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch The PHP script has to be constantly running to send keepalive packets. Can I still send commands to the interactive shell if I run it from Quercus?